# Is "I will get understood" a valid way to say that someone is going to be able to understand you?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, word-difference

I'm encountering that is commonly said "make myself understood" and I thought that the way that I'm saying it is wrong. But I'm not certainly sure if it is wrong or just have a different meaning.

This situation is not from a specific subject in English classes or something like that, but from a self-learning process that I've made through the time.

Is it wrong to say "get understood"? and Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might hear it in informal conversation, but technically I don't think of it as good usage. I can't speak for others, but Americans frequently use "to get" as a catchall verb. In this context, you might use:

```
I will be understood ...
```

e.g.

```
If I speak clearly, I will be understood.
```

although the use of active voice instead of passive voice makes for clearer language:

```
If I speak clearly, my audience will understand me.
```

Sometimes, of course, you can't easily re-work the ideas you want to express in active voice. Native speakers have trouble speaking and writing in active voice, so don't despair if trying to use active voice drives you crazy. The effort will improve your spoken and written usage of the language.

Comment: Nope - you won't hear that at all from any native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly wrong to say

> I will get understood

people will understand what you mean, more commonly heard is

> I will be understood

to say you will make *someone* understand you.  Though it is a fairly big statement to say that one can "make" *someone else* understand.

One scenario might be that *someone* asks you: "How will you get them to understand you?", and you might say, as you look at your gun, "I will be understood."

Comment: It's not exactly wrong, but it's not exactly right, either. Perhaps the best way to explain it might be: "get understood" isn't **idiomatic**.